# How to find the duplicates in a list of dicts based on 2 dict fields?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So let's say I have a list:

```
new_list = [
    {a:'2', b:'3', c:'1'},
    {a:'1', b:'2', c:'1'},
    {a:'1', b:'2', c:'1'},
    {a:'1', b:'4', c:'1'},
    {a:'2', b:'2', c:'1'},
    {a:'3', b:'2', c:'1'}]
```

So i only want the duplicates with `a` and `b` fields.
expected:

```
final_list = [{a:'1', b:'2', c:'1'}]
```

I tried using sets but I'm new to python so got a bit lost

Comment: Please fix your code, `{a:'1',b:'2',c:'1'}` is not a valid dictionary.

Comment: Are `a, b, c` supposed to be strings? If so they should be quoted. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: What is this result exactly? Is it all subsequent dicts with `a:'1', b:'2'` after the first occurrence, or is it the unique values with `a:'1', b:'2'`, or something else? Please [edit] to clarify. Showing us what you've tried would help. "Duplicate" is a loaded word, unfortunately, so is "unique" to an extent.

Comment: Do duplicates need to be adjacent to count?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

```
new_list = [
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1},
    {'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 1},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
    {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 3},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3},
]

final_list = []

for dictionary in new_list:
    if dictionary in final_list:
        continue
    count = 0
    for dictionary_ in new_list:
        if all([dictionary['a']==dictionary_['a'], dictionary['b']==dictionary_['b']]):
            count += 1
            if count > 1:
                final_list.append(dictionary)
                break
        
print(final_list)
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2}]
```

Comment: Yes correct, thanks! I ended up doing it with sets. The mistake I made was not considering that I can concat all the keys to form a big key value for the purpose of the set and then store all the dupes in a separate list after comparing to set. Was a quick one just novice Python things.

Comment: Great! I'm almost certain there's a better way of solving the problem but I don't have the time to improve performance at the moment. If performance is an issue then keep eye on this in case someone comes along and provides a better answer.